# WSO2 API Manager - Auth Type "None" leads to APISecurityException

Tags: api, wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to use my API through the Swagger UI through the WSO2 API Manager:
Me->Browser->SwaggerUI->WSO2->MyBackend

Now I got the problem, that Swagger UI always gives me:

```
{  "error": "no response from server" }
```

I was making some research and figured out, that the Problem here is associated to CORS. While I am attempting a GET request, the Firefox sends an OPTION request first (because of CORS) to the WSO2 gateway.

Now the same scenario is explained and described here as well:

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1819

The solution/workarounds described in the links is, that in the API publisher you have to create an endpoint for the requested resource with method OPTION and to set the auth type of that OPTION endpoint to "none".

However this doesn't work for me, since I get an exception in WSO, when the request is passed in.

1. The HTTP Request going into WSO2:

> TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,707] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "OPTIONS /bankapi/v1/cashAccounts HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
>   TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,707] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Host: 10.88.13.104:8243[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
>   TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,707] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
>   TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,707] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
>   TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,708] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
>   TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,708] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
>   TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,708] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Origin: http://10.88.13.104:8080[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
>   TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,708] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
>   TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,708] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
>   TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,708] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}

2. The exception and stack trace:

> TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-07 09:32:50,878] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failure {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Access failure for API: /bankapi, version: v1 with key: null
>       at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:212)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:94)
>       at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:284)
>       at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:83)
>       at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:64)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344)
>       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

The important thing here is 2.... there is an error while authenticating even though the auth type is none and the authentication should always be successful. The request is *not even* forwarded to the backend (this is why my question is not a duplicate, but there is a very different problem underlying).

I am running WSO2 API Manager in version 1.8.0 on Windows (the binary package you can download on the WSO2 site).
Can you help me out here? Am I missing something? Is this a plain bug (it looks to me that way)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross domain problems with WSO2 API Manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304290/cross-domain-problems-with-wso2-api-manager)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. The accepted answer suggest to put in the method OPTION for the resource with the auth type "none", which i did. The resulting problem in that topic was, that the backend doesn't support the OPTION method. My problem in contrast (as the log tells) is that WSO2 gives an authentication exception (despite the "none" auth type) and won't even send the request to the backend.